# Callback from AngularJS to Jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, callback

I've got some general Jquery functions, on every page on my site. For example parallax footer is realized with Jquery. The function triggers on window scroll, window resize and sets position / height / etc of the footer.

```
function showFooter(){
        var scrolltop = $(document).scrollTop();
        var winheight = $(window).height();
        var docHeight = $(document).outerHeight()
        if(scrolltop + winheight >= docHeight - fHeight){
            var fac = 1.3;
            var footerBottom = Math.abs(winheight + scrolltop - docHeight) / fac;
            if(winheight - 100 <= fHeight){
                var fc = Math.abs((winheight - 100) - fHeight);
                footerBottom = Math.abs(winheight + scrolltop - docHeight) / fac - fc;
                if(footerBottom <= 0){
                    footerBottom = 0;
                }
            }
            $('footer').css('bottom', footerBottom + 'px');
        }
    }
```

On one of my pages I've got little AngularJS app. It renders elements with ng-repeat and depending on user actions it shows different amount of elements. Height of the page changes and Jquery does not know about it => some elements that should be resized/repositioned with Jquery are shown wrong.

(I can provide the code, but there's nothing special - ng-repeat for a scope object and a custom filter to show items in categories)

Is there a nice solution to solve the problem?

I've made AngularJS to scroll the page 1px down and then back every time after everything is rendered. It's not visible for a user, but triggers needed Jquery functions in $(window).scroll listner. But I understand, that it's a dirty solution... and it does not work if there is no scroll on the page.

I've tried to use Jquery listners for DOM changes, but it triggers so many events, that I worry about website performance.

So... which way sould I go? I did not found any clean solutions. Are there some?

Comment: Could use a custom directive that triggers `$(window).resize()`

Comment: you mean the same way, I scroll the window +/-1px, but resize instead of scroll to solve the problem with "short" pages without scroll?

Comment: Really hard to help more without some sort of [mcve]

Comment: I've provided some Jquery code... and about Angular - there's nothing special... ng-repeat and a filter that changes the amount of displaed items...